# What's the maximum number of repetitions allowed in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

i have some little script which check is there is some new content on website. I created infinite loop and script stops at some time, i think about 2700 repetition. Is there some restriction on number of repetition? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Do While True
    ....
Loop
```

No, there is no loop repetition limit.

Comment: is it possible that website counting visit of same IP address or with cookie and then restrict enter

Comment: @josiplegionares, yes, the described scenario is possible. Or the components used to do the query can have an error, or the code can leak memory or it is possible that a non correctly handled error condition breaks the code, or .... But in all this scenarios the limits are not impossed by vbscript itself.